# angular dropdown directive won't populate with pre-selected data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

My application is built in RoR and has two edit modes: normal and advanced. I’m bootstrapping to AngularJs the Normal view in which, users can edit some of the fields. In this view I have a table with seven columns, each of these columns receives and passes data from and to a json object. This view features a table and in the first row I'm using ng-repeat to populate with data the first seven rows using Angular’s limitTo filter. 
Up to this point everything works fine and the two way data binding works like a charm. The problem comes with one of the columns: a dropdown with integers going from one to ten, let’s call this column “row order”.  The issue is this: in spite of the model being correct for all the other rows (and these rows therefore working as expected: get data from the advanced view or, accept new values as per the user and store the data in the json object) in the case of this dropdown, things just won’t work, as it only will display an empty slot (the very first before the numbers), when I select a number I get a 422 error. What else do I need to add to my controller? 
As I said, the other rows follow the same exact model of series.* and everything works fine. Below: the table cell and the controller.

```
<td ng-controller="rowOrderCtrl" >
   <select class="form-control" ng-model="series.row_order" id="chart_data_series_attributes_{{$index}}_row_order" name="chart[data_series_attributes][{{$index}}][row_order]" ng-change="updateChart()" ng-options="row.value as row.key for row in rowOrder">
   </select>
</td>
```

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp').controller('rowOrderCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.rowOrder = [
    { key: 1, value: 1 },
    { key: 2, value: 2 },
    { key: 3, value: 3 },
    { key: 4, value: 4 },
    { key: 5, value: 5 },
    { key: 6, value: 6 },
    { key: 7, value: 7 },
    { key: 8, value: 8 },
    { key: 9, value: 9 },
    { key: 10, value: 10 }
  ];
});
```

```
  def create_chart_data_series(chart)
    ((current_upper)..10).each {|counter|
#      charts.data_series << DataSeries.build(:row_order => counter)
      chart.data_series.build(:row_order => counter)
    }
  end
```

Comment: what is the value of `series.row_order` ?

Comment: series.row_order can be any number from 1 to 10, for each row in the panel, if that makes any sense

Comment: after doing some research, I think that probably this array, neeeds to be serialized?